# jQuery datatable td html is getting update for inner table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery datatable 1.10.12. I have inner table within the datatable. When I am trying to update the html of fnRowCallback, then the problem occurs. As there nested table within the datatable it apply the callback function for inner table not in main table when datatable is drawn. The table should look like this:

[image]

But when row call back it shows something like this:

[image]

I know this is happening here:

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            if (aData.DT_RowId == undefined) {
                return true;
            }
            $('td:eq(2)', nRow).html(getFormattedTable("food", nRow, aData));
            $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html(getFormattedTable("snacks", nRow, aData));
            $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html(getActionButtons(nRow, aData));
            return nRow;
        },
```

Here `td:eq` is overlapped with the child table. I don't know how to stop it. I have searched for it but no luck.

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle  or jsbin example ?

Comment: no, as it is simple enough to understand